# How to set default date as 1 using boottstarp datepicker with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datepicker, php-carbon

in my date form input i will select only month and year but when i insert into database its saving month and year with current date. but i want set date  1st of slected month im using carbon also

```
 {!! Form::text('vessel_date',null,['class' => 'date-own form-control' , 'id'=>'date-own-id']) !!}
```

Controller :

```
$input['vessel_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-Y', $request->vessel_date)->toDateString();
```

JS :

```
$('.date-own').datepicker({
        minViewMode: 1,
        format: 'mm-yyyy'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I have used Carbon to get the first of the month in a recent application:

```
// (year, month, day)
Carbon::createFromDate(null, null, 1)
```

Year, Month, and Day being integers.

To format before insert/update (depending on target DB format) `->format('M d Y')`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. you can find it [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdate).

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update');
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', new Date(2011, 2, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer above my comment, also kindly check your date format of your DBMS (e.g if it is same with your datepicker).

Answer (score 0):

answer is

```
$('.date-own').datepicker({
        minViewMode: 1,
        format: 'mm-yyyy'
    });
```